# 3D Cube, calculate vertices with coortinate of Center and diagonal

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, cube, geometry-surface

I wanted to know if there is a method to calculate the vertices of a 3D cube (x, y, z) knowing:
- The center (coordinate Cx, Cy, Cz)
- Coordinate "min", understood as the minimum vertex of the cube (with coordinates mx, my, mz)
- Coordinate "max", defined as the maximum vertex of the cube (with coordinates Mx, My, Mz)
- And its diagonal (length given by the distance between min and max).

With this information I would calculate:
- All 8 vertices of the cube
- The length of your side of the cube

It's possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. If you are now thinking *Yes, but how ?*, then ask that question.

Comment: the question is quite clear, if you are not a machine understand that the question is not what is before the question mark, but that's what I wrote above, that is what I would come up with these data.
Quiet anyway, I already solved itself.
And if you have to answer so I better not answer me at all.
Thanks and bye